# How to add custom data annotations on model to display in Swagger UI

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, swagger-ui

I'm working an Asp.Net Web Api project and added Swashbuckle to generate API documentation. Everything works fine except that when I look at the swagger-ui specially for Post and Put requests. Swagger-UI shows Model with a bunch of properties (apparently the model properties which are sent in the request body). The properties which are decorated using .net data annotations such as **Required** are honored by Swagger so it does't show **optional** anymore in-front of those properties in the UI. But I have also created some custom data annotations such as **Property A is only required if Property B is not present**. How can I make Swagger-UI show my custom data annotations as well?